# Activity is not an enclosing class (android studio)

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development. I am trying to code when the button in MainActivity gets clicked, it should go to the next activity (EnableLocationActivity). I get an error that the activity (EnableLocation) is not an enclosing class.

How can I fix this?

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button openingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_main_next);
    openingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent enableLocIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnableLocationActivity.this);
            startActivity(enableLocIntent);
        }
    });

   }
}
```

And...

**EnableLocationActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class EnableLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enable_location);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent enableLocIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnableLocationActivity.this);
```

should be

```
Intent enableLocIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnableLocationActivity.class);
```

`Intent` constructor your using expects a `Class` as second argument.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, in the project panel, why are some files txt green and others red? what does that mean?

Comment: @KatZee sorry, didn't get what you mean by that?

Comment: Have you added version control to your project.. The green files are the new ones and red are the modified.

Comment: @Audi good point, might be the case or may be just something to do with a custom theme

Comment: @KatZee Java files have a red icon.  Gradle files / layout files are probably green/yellow

Answer (score 3):

**Intent enableLocIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnableLocationActivity.this);**

The second argument of the Intent should be EnableLocationActivity.**class**
because **.this** can be used to refer current activity and *EnableLocationActivity* is not your current activity, it is your next activity. So your code should be:-

**Intent enableLocIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnableLocationActivity.class);**